# Cannot assign to non-existent default property

Tags: multithreading, qml

I can not capture images in new thread
can you tell me what does it mean?

```
import qyvlik.thread.runnable 0.1   
import qyvlik.utility 0.1
import QtMultimedia 5.5
QmlRunnable
{
    id: runnable

    Camera
    {
        id: cam
    }

    onMessageReceived:
    {
        cam.imageCapture.capture()
    }
}
```

**EDIT** (@derM): It seems [**this**](https://github.com/qyvlik/QmlThread) is the source of the third-party modules.

Comment: It only means that you cannot capture images. But seriously, you have to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article before asking an question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @KevinKrammer pointed out:

The error appears, as your class `QmlRunnable` has no [`default property`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-default-example.html), to which your `Camera`-object could be assigned. This is standard for most non-Item-QObjects in QML.

The author of your class knows of this problem, therefore he defines a property to store his `DirSize`-object in his [example](https://github.com/qyvlik/QmlThread/blob/master/thread_in_qml/qml/thread/thread_dir_size.qml)

**Example**:

```
import qyvlik.thread.runnable 0.1
import qyvlik.utility 0.1


QmlRunnable {
    id: runnable

    readonly property var __: DirSize {
        id: dirsize
    }

    onMessageReceived: {
        console.time("dirsize")
        sendMessage(dirsize.dirSize(message));
        console.timeEnd("dirsize")
    }
}
```

**From this I guess the solution would be this:**

```
import qyvlik.thread.runnable 0.1
import qyvlik.utility 0.1
import QtMultimedia 5.5
QmlRunnable
{
    id: runnable

    property Camera cam: Camera // <--- create a property to assign it to.
    {
    }

    onMessageReceived:
    {
        cam.imageCapture.capture()
    }
}
```

Comment: one more detail please, where can I write onImageCaptured:{} ??

Answer (score 0):

You are using some third party QML modules, one of which apparently provides a `QmlRunnable` type.

Without any information on that type, such as a link to its documentation, the error would suggest that it is the one that does not have a default property.

When you try to create the `Camera` object inside the `QmlRunnable` the engine will try to assign that instance to the "parent's" default property.

Again, without any knowledge about the type it is difficult to provide any help.

Comment: That's doesn't look like an answer.

Comment: @folibis: But it is. It is a common mistake to use this syntax when there is no `default property` defined. And that is the case here, too. This is the best possible answer for this miserably question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the QmlRunnable can not use the gui class, because it is Undetermined behavior